# Error Number: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: sql-server

Existen ya algunas preguntas con el mismo error, pero no resuelven mi problema.

```
SELECT `pedidos`.`idpedido`, `pedidos`.`idusuario`, dayofmonth(pedidos.fecha_pedido) as fecha_compra_dia, DATE_FORMAT(pedidos.fecha_pedido, '%Y-%m-%d') as fecha_compra, dayofmonth(pedidos.fecha_pedido) as dia, month(pedidos.fecha_pedido) as mes, (case when (dayname(pedidos.fecha_pedido) = 'Monday') then 'Lunes' when (dayname(pedidos.fecha_pedido) = 'Tuesday') then 'Martes' when (dayname(pedidos.fecha_pedido) = 'Wednesday') then 'Miércoles' when (dayname(pedidos.fecha_pedido) = 'Thursday') then 'Jueves' when (dayname(pedidos.fecha_pedido) = 'Friday') then 'Viernes' when (dayname(pedidos.fecha_pedido) = 'Saturday') then 'Sábado' when (dayname(pedidos.fecha_pedido) = 'Sunday') then 'Domingo' else dayname(pedidos.fecha_pedido) end) AS dia_semana, year(pedidos.fecha_pedido) as año, DATE_FORMAT(pedidos.fecha_pedido, '%H:%i:%s') as hora, `pedidos`.`envia_nombres` as `nombres`, `pedidos`.`envia_telefono` as `telefonosolicita`, `pedidos`.`envia_celular` as `celularsolicita`, `pedidos`.`envia_correo` as `correosolicita`, (case when facturacion.tipo_documento = 1 then 'boleta' when facturacion.tipo_documento = 2 then 'factura' else facturacion.tipo_documento end) as tipofactura, `pedidos`.`metodo_pago` as `tipo_pago`, if(pedidos.exportar=1, 'A', 'I') as exportado, (case when pedidos.estado_pago = 0 then 'Denegado' when pedidos.estado_pago = 1 then 'Pendiente'when pedidos.estado_pago = 2 then 'Pagado' else pedidos.estado_pago end) as estadopago, (case when pedidos.estado_entrega = 1 then 'Pendiente' when pedidos.estado_entrega = 2 then 'Entregado' when pedidos.estado_entrega = 3 then 'Anulado' else pedidos.estado_entrega end) as estadoentrega, `pedidos`.`total_pedido_soles` as `total`, (case when (select 1 from usuarios u where (pedidos.envia_correo = u.correo)) then 'C' else 'I' end) as tipocliente FROM `pedidos` LEFT JOIN `entrega` ON `entrega`.`idpedido` = `pedidos`.`idpedido` LEFT JOIN `facturacion` ON `facturacion`.`idpedido` = `pedidos`.`idpedido` WHERE `pedidos`.`fecha_pedido` >= '2019-06-20 ' AND `pedidos`.`fecha_pedido` < '2019-07-01' AND `pedidos`.`exportar` = 1 AND ( `pedidos`.`estado_pago` = 2 OR `pedidos`.`estado_pago` = 3 ) ORDER BY `pedidos`.`idpedido` DESC
```

Intento exportar los pedidos de mi tabla con una fecha de inicio y una fecha fin.

Hasta hace unos días no he tenido inconveniente, hasta hoy que intenté exportar del inicio del mes pasado hasta el final de ese mes que me arroja ese error, lo raro es que solo me arroja ese error con la fecha del **30/06/2019** todas las demás fechas me exporta normal.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tu subquery te está regresando mas de un registro, y creo que se debe a que en lugar de "SELECT TOP 1" tu código dice "SELECT 1", tu código quedaría así:

```
SELECT 
`pedidos`.`idpedido`, 
`pedidos`.`idusuario`, 
dayofmonth(pedidos.fecha_pedido) as fecha_compra_dia, 
DATE_FORMAT(pedidos.fecha_pedido, '%Y-%m-%d') as fecha_compra, 
dayofmonth(pedidos.fecha_pedido) as dia, 
month(pedidos.fecha_pedido) as mes, 
(case when (dayname(pedidos.fecha_pedido) = 'Monday') then 
'Lunes' 
when (dayname(pedidos.fecha_pedido) = 'Tuesday') then 
'Martes' 
when (dayname(pedidos.fecha_pedido) = 'Wednesday') then 
'Miércoles' 
when (dayname(pedidos.fecha_pedido) = 'Thursday') then 
'Jueves' 
when (dayname(pedidos.fecha_pedido) = 'Friday') then 
'Viernes' 
when (dayname(pedidos.fecha_pedido) = 'Saturday') then 
'Sábado' 
when (dayname(pedidos.fecha_pedido) = 'Sunday') then 
'Domingo' 
else 
dayname(pedidos.fecha_pedido) end) AS dia_semana, 
year(pedidos.fecha_pedido) as año, 
DATE_FORMAT(pedidos.fecha_pedido, '%H:%i:%s') as hora, 
`pedidos`.`envia_nombres` as `nombres`, 
`pedidos`.`envia_telefono` as `telefonosolicita`, 
`pedidos`.`envia_celular` as `celularsolicita`, 
`pedidos`.`envia_correo` as `correosolicita`, 
(case 
when facturacion.tipo_documento = 1 then 
'boleta' 
when facturacion.tipo_documento = 2 then 
'factura' 
else 
facturacion.tipo_documento 
end) as tipofactura, 
`pedidos`.`metodo_pago` as `tipo_pago`, 
if(pedidos.exportar=1, 'A', 'I') as exportado, 
(case 
when pedidos.estado_pago = 0 then 
'Denegado' 
when pedidos.estado_pago = 1 then 
'Pendiente'
when pedidos.estado_pago = 2 then 
'Pagado' 
else 
pedidos.estado_pago 
end) as estadopago, 
(case 
when pedidos.estado_entrega = 1 then 
'Pendiente' 
when pedidos.estado_entrega = 2 then 
'Entregado' 
when pedidos.estado_entrega = 3 then 
'Anulado' 
else 
pedidos.estado_entrega 
end) as estadoentrega, 
`pedidos`.`total_pedido_soles` as `total`, 
(case 
when (select TOP 1 from usuarios u where (pedidos.envia_correo = u.correo)) then 'C' else 'I' end) as tipocliente -- AQUI ESTA TU ERROR, CAMBIA ESTA LINEA
FROM 
`pedidos` LEFT JOIN `entrega` ON `entrega`.`idpedido` = `pedidos`.`idpedido` 
LEFT JOIN `facturacion` ON `facturacion`.`idpedido` = `pedidos`.`idpedido` 
WHERE 
`pedidos`.`fecha_pedido` >= '2019-06-20 ' 
AND 
`pedidos`.`fecha_pedido` < '2019-07-01' 
AND `pedidos`.`exportar` = 1 
AND ( `pedidos`.`estado_pago` = 2 OR `pedidos`.`estado_pago` = 3 ) 
ORDER BY 
`pedidos`.`idpedido` DESC
```